Basic code blocks in LCOV/GCOV branch coverage
We are using LCOV/GCOV to produce test coverage of our projects. In the .info file, there is information:
BRDA:<line_number>,<block>,<branch>,<taken>
How should I understand the block number? I have a .info file with some information:
BRDA:139,0,0,36
BRDA:139,0,1,81
BRDA:139,0,2,0
BRDA:139,0,3,4
BRDA:139,0,4,4
BRDA:139,0,5,628

The corresponding source code is:
switch (cmdType) {
    case 1:
        xxxx
        break;
    case 2:
        xxxx
        break;
    case 3:
        xxxx
        break;
    case 4:
        xxxx
        break;
    case 5:
        xxxx
        break;
    default: {
        xxxx
        break;
    }
}

I understand that a basic block is a sequence of continuous instructions that are not interrupted by branches or jump instructions during program execution. So why does the code here all belong to the same block number 0? How should I understand the basic blocks here?
The different cases of my codeshould correspond to different basic code blocks
